# How to add printer in Centos7

Tags: centos-7, canon-pixma

I am trying print from my PC centos7. So, when i tried to add printer through print setting, I couldn't find the driver for Canon MF240 Series UFRII LT. Please assist.

I have captured screenshots.

[image: Printing Troubleshooter log]

[image: print setting - localhost]

[image: print properties Canon MF240 Series on localhost]

[image: New printer - searching for drivers]

Comment: Proprietary drivers are seldom included in any Linux distros. Get them from the manufacturer and install. If you have any doubt or are stuck in some step of the process please ask a proper question describing exactly that, here or at [unix.se].

Comment: @MichaelBay : Thanks for the prompt response. 
I have printer driver CD but it shows driver only for windows. I am stuck in getting driver for printer. 
Also, How to transfer this question to Unix & Linux ?

Comment: The question is on topic, it may fit better at [unix.se] but it's fine here as well. And I said "get them from the manufacturer" implying download them from the website. https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/imageclass-mf247dw/imageclass-mf247dw?tab=drivers_downloads

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks it worked. All i need was to do following things:

Comment: 1. install 64 bit drivers (RPM)
2. Select old PPD when asked for setting option
3. Print Test Page.